# CSS text width set

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem in CSS3/CSS so I'm working on a website I'm done with the layout and pages 
so lets say I'm hanging around the website and went inside some post 
the problem if I have to long post it's going to go over line!
I have width `=600`, that's for the post_warrper,
but still if I add some text it still go out side the box if it's to long!
I tried to set `p` to `600px` but it don't work 
I tried to use overflow and I did it with the scroll it works good but still it dont look "that good"
and if I set it to hidden when I add any new post I have to take care of it realy good or the post
not going to mean anything to the user
I think you can understand what I'm saying hope you got my point!

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: Add your html and css code to the question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `word-wrap: break-word;`, it will force wrapping to prevent what I think you are trying to describe.